# Fast way to check if binary image has split in two

Tags: performance, language-agnostic

I know how to find connected components efficiently. I am looking for the best way to find if a binary image that contains a single component still contains only one component. Inbetween there are losses of one or two pixels.

I have heard of edge-based approches and I think something like that might be good, but I can't find anything about them on the internet except that they are inferior to other approaches in labeling connected components.

If you know anything related to this, please post a link.

Comment: "I am looking for the best way to find if a binary image that contains a single component still contains only one component. Inbetween there are losses of one or two pixels." -- could you please clarify this? "Inbetween" what? How are pixels lost?

Comment: 1. The image is created 2. Pixels are removed 3. Is there still only one component? If yes, jump to 2

Comment: @Florian Sorry, I forgot to ping you.